# Best way to handle multiple screen aspects on mobile

Tags: unity-game-engine, screen-resolution

So, I have been been looking a lot into this topic and the internet seems to be rather vague and divided. I have found that a lot of people handle different screen sizes and aspect ratios by using certain scripts to scale and anchor game objects.

Some people say that you should have assets of different sizes, and enable/disable them based on the screen size. While this method (to me) seems more efficient, it feels like this is suggested less than the other method.

So I would like to ask what the best method is. (Or if there is such a thing as the "best")

Answer (score 3):

The best way is by using a Canvas Scaler and making good use of the anchor-point of the UI elements in your scene and using Layout Groups, this way they will fit nicely into almost all of the aspect ratios.

A few videos covering these topics:
[Jimmy Vegas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ov0o111Joi0&ab_channel=JimmyVegas)
[Unity 3D With Scott](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=95q79j0lNYA&ab_channel=Unity3DWithScott)
[Cat Trap Studios](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RWcwEAILOCA&ab_channel=CatTrapStudios)

Comment: I have experimented so much with the canvas scaler and it doesn't seem to work for me. It does scale the objects somewhat, but it looks awful when changing the aspect ratio

Comment: Unless you are trying to support portait and landscape modes at the same time, it doesn't look awful if you, as the answer says, make **good** use of the anchor-point. Make `Canvas Scaler` to scale with width or height and either set it to 0 (keep width) or to 1 (keep height). Then position your element knowing that the screen will expand/shrink in one direction (width or height depending on the setting mentioned before). For supporting both landscape and portrait, I would suggest making different prefabs for layouts and instantiate them based on the aspect (< 1 -> vertical, > 1 - horizontal).

Comment: I'm only supporting portrait mode. The problem with this is that there will be a bigger gap between the objects and the border of the screen when the width of the device is bigger.

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve, even spacing? Use `HorizontalLayout`. Need to keep size - you'll have to adjust spacing. Use a combination `GridLayout` and a script that would adjust the spacing based on elements width inside the layout and the width of the layout itself. If you decide to use layout components, don't forget to disable them after they have layed out the components. Otherwise these will try to do all the calculations again and again when the canvas gets dirty, and canvas gets dirty pretty much every time any of its children properties are changed.